# Select query and Insert using select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query like this :

```
select 
    SUM(Percentage) as SUM, 
    @cnt as Count, 
    (SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Percentage 
from 
    #Temp2 
group By 
    RowNumber 
order by 
    Percentage desc
```

`Percentage` column of above query looks something like this :

[image]

Then I have a query just below above query :

```
Update dbo.ResultsStored 
set FinalSearchSeral = @searchNumber, 
    ModifiedAt = getDate(), 
    PercentMatch = t.Perc 
from 
    (select (SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Perc 
     from #Temp2 
     GROUP BY RowNumber) t  
where 
    HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)

select * 
from dbo.ResultsStored 
order by PercentMatch desc
```

Note: `where` clause here is not a problem as I intend to update rows only with matched hashcode code.

The results from select statement are confusing me.

Above select statement results in Percentage column with these results:

[image]

I do not understand why is there a  different in percentages calculated with above queries ?

However, the results are correct with first query and something goes wrong in second one.

Comment: in the update, you need to join the query with ResultsStored, what will be the join column(s)?

Comment: @Farhęg:RowId column could be the join column but I do not realize why exactly that is needed and why is there a difference in results in above queries

Comment: ok, I posted an answer. hope it be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the result is expected and in update you need to specify which field should take which value from query I mean use `Join`, try this one (as you mentioned in comments if rowid can be a join column):

```
Update dbo.ResultsStored 
set dbo.ResultsStored.FinalSearchSeral = @searchNumber, 
    dbo.ResultsStored.ModifiedAt = getDate(), 
    dbo.ResultsStored.PercentMatch = t.Perc 
from 
    dbo.ResultsStored
join
    (select RowId,(SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Perc 
     from #Temp2 
     GROUP BY RowId) t
 on dbo.ResultsStored.RowId=t.RowId
    and dbo.ResultsStored.HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
```